# Kendo UI mobile and Dataviz

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-dataviz

I am trying to use DataViz with Kendo UI mobile by referencing kendo.all.min.js file. The click events of the listview do not work. If the reference is changed to kendo.mobile.min.js then everything works fine.

Here are the referenced files:

```
<link href="kendo/styles/kendo.dataviz.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="kendo/styles/kendo.dataviz.flat.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the question here is "How to get the listview click events to work". Without seeing your code, I can only suggest a couple things:

1. Use the debug/developer tool in Chrome or the AppBuilder simulator and check your console for any reference errors. One reference error or javascript error can cause your whole page to stop working.
2. In addition, check in your directory ./kendo/js/ and confirm that you actually named the file kendo.all.min.js.

This is a start, hope it helps.